# conditional (SFINAE) override

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to do this:

```
struct A
{
  virtual int f() const { return 0; }
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A
{
  template <typename U = T,
    typename std::enable_if<...some condition involving U...>::type>
  int f() const { return 1; }
};
```

Caveat, I can't inherit class templates (use static overrides). Is this sort of construct allowed and can the template member B::f() override the member A::f()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct B : A
{
  ...
};

template <typename T>
struct B<T, typename std::enable_if<...some condition...>::type>:
  A
{
  virtual int f() const override { return 1; }
};
```

where we have two versions of `B<T>`, one for which the condition is true (the `enable_if` one), one for which the condition is false (the default one).

If you wanted to be able to reuse your default `B` implementation, you could even do this:

```
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct B : A
{
  ...
};

template <typename T>
struct B<T,  typename std::enable_if<...some condition...>::type>:
  B<T, bool>
{
  virtual int f() const override { return 1; }
};
```

where we inherit from the "false" case in the "true" case.  But that is a bit dirty to me -- I'd rather put the common implementation in some third spot (`B_impl`) rather than that hack.  (That also lets you static assert that the second argument is `void` in the first case of `B`).